# How do I select every pair of 2 sequential elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone please help me to work out how to achieve the following? I have a set of divs of unknown size. Each div has a class of .feature. I need to run a jQuery script to find all divs with .feature and then find all children as a series of pairs. Each pair will then be submitted to a further jQuery function.

For example:

```
1. <div.feature/>
2. <div.feature/>
3. <div.feature/>
4. <div.feature/>
5. <div.feature/>
```

The result should be that 1+2 and 3+4 get paired together such that I can then call another jQuery function on each of these individual sets.

I know that I can simply wrap each pair in an outer div and then find each wrapper divs children but I'd like to avoid changing the markup if possible.

Comment: Can you post the actual markup so we're clear?  What you posted isn't HTML...

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry I was in a hurry at the time. You're right, I've not posted valid markup but each element was menat to indicate a div with a class of "feature".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var pairs = [];
$('div.feature').each(function(i, div) {
  var i_over_2 = Math.floor(i / 2);
  if (!pairs[i_over_2]) pairs[i_over_2] = $();
  pairs[i_over_2] = pairs[i_over_2].add(div);
});
$.each(pairs, function(i, p) {
  p.doSomethingToAPair();
});
```

The idea is to build up an array of jQuery objects.

**edit** looks like 1.4 added "$()" to get an empty jQuery object.

**edit again** durr Javascript has floats :-)

Hey @Adam: if we had this jQuery extension (this is a toy version of course):

```
jQuery.fn.zip = function(s) {
  var o = $(s);
  return this.map(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).add($(o[i]));
  });
};
```

then we could build the "pairs" array like this:

```
var pairs = $('div.feature:even').zip('div.feature:odd');
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I can't test right now but that looks about right.

Comment: I'm testing now; I'll be done in a sec if *!&(# firefox will cooperate

Comment: This looks strange, $() equals $(document)

Comment: @David that was true up until jQuery version 1.4

Comment: Isn't this somewhat complicated?

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks! I missed that, and it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Adam well complexity is in the eye of the beholder :-)  When I first wrote it, making believe it was C, I didn't need the temp. variable. If there were a jQuery "zip" builtin, you could zip together the :even and :odd divs to make the pairs array, and that'd be simpler.

Comment: 5+ years later and, with a little modification due to Grunt being picky about inline if statements, this worked brilliantly for a project just now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

#### idea

```
$('div.feature:even').each(function(){
  var t = $(this);
  var paired = t.add( $('div.feature:eq('+(t.index()+1)+')', t.parent()) );
  //add to array, call function...
}
```

May need little tweaking in order to work for you - it's untested.

#### preview

http://jsbin.com/okize/7

Comment: I used similar code for this to get pairs based on the even set elements, but i only used t.index(), not +1, because :eq is 0 index based. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let's jump to the assumption that you can fix the HTML to make it valid, and it looks like:

```
<div class='feature'></div>
<div class='feature'></div>
<div class='feature'></div>
<div class='feature'></div>
<div class='feature'></div>
<div class='feature'></div>
```

You can then use a selector like:

```
$("div:odd")
```

or

```
$("div:even")
```

more like:

```
$("div:even").children(':even');
```

NOTE: 0 based index, so 2,4,etc (normal count) are ODD...

Comment: Doesn't the question asked for adjacent pairs, not even or odds?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to format a set of divs into a two column table:

```
$('.feature:even').each(function () {
    $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll("<tr>");
});
$('.feature').wrap('<td>');
$('tr').wrapAll('<table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution that I used for a elements of a blog but I think it could be applied to this problem, I hope help you, it is the same I have a list of element and every li element has inside two div element and what I want is to apply the same style in step of every 2 elements, I mean, 1+2 Same Style and 3+4 Other Style and so on, 5+6 the same style of the 1+2. So here is What I did.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="photo">PHOTO</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="photo">PHOTO</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="photo">PHOTO</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="photo">PHOTO</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="photo">PHOTO</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="photo">PHOTO</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="photo">PHOTO</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="photo">PHOTO</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var row = 0;
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  // Here is when you loop every two elements
  if ( index % 2 == 0)
  {
    if (row % 2 == 0 )
    {
      //console.log("index "+index + " row" + row);
      first_element = $( "ul li:eq("+index+")" ).addClass( "blue-bg" );
      second_element = $( "ul li:eq("+(index+1)+")" ).addClass( "blue-bg" );
      $(first_element).find('.photo').addClass( "pull-left" );
      $(first_element).find('.text').addClass( "pull-right" );
      $(second_element).find('.photo').addClass( "pull-left" );
      $(second_element).find('.text').addClass( "pull-right" );
      row = 1; // make row value odd
    }
    else
    {
      //console.log("index "+index + " row" + row);
      third_element = $( "ul li:eq("+index+")" ).addClass( "red-bg" );
      four_element = $( "ul li:eq("+(index+1)+")" ).addClass( "red-bg" );
      $(third_element).find('.photo').addClass( "pull-right" );
      $(third_element).find('.text').addClass( "pull-left" );
      $(four_element).find('.photo').addClass( "pull-right" );
      $(four_element).find('.text').addClass( "pull-left" );
      row = 0;  // make row vale even
    }
  }
});
```

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8n8q49nL/)

Comment: This is very a complicated solution and lowers down performance extensively. Not recommended.