# jquery - set height to every 2 or 3 elements

Tags: jquery, height, equals

I have several divs on a page in columns of 2, so every 2 divs needs to be the same height. As far as I can tell the plugins available for to force equal height do all elements the same height, I just need each pair to be the same height.

my markup looks like this

etc

I have the following jquery which works, but I am sure it can be done easier

```
    {
    var rowOneHeight = Math.max($('div.large:eq(0)').height(),$('div.large:eq(1)').height());
    $('div.large:eq(0)').css('min-height', rowOneHeight);
    $('div.large:eq(1)').css('min-height', rowOneHeight);

    var rowTwoHeight = Math.max($('div.large:eq(2)').height(),$('div.large:eq(3)').height());
    $('div.large:eq(2)').css('min-height', rowTwoHeight);
    $('div.large:eq(3)').css('min-height', rowTwoHeight);

    var rowThreeHeight = Math.max($('div.large:eq(4)').height(),$('div.large:eq(5)').height());
    $('div.large:eq(4)').css('min-height', rowThreeHeight);
    $('div.large:eq(5)').css('min-height', rowThreeHeight);
```

}

it would also need the same to be done with a group of three divs.
Thanks

Comment: I did see this question/answer which looks potentially useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358559/how-do-i-select-every-pair-of-2-sequential-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 8):

You could do a loop with [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to loop through in sets of 2, like this:

```
var elems = $("div.large");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i+=2) {
  var divs = elems.slice(i, i+2), 
      height = Math.max(divs.eq(0).height(), divs.eq(1).height());
  divs.css('min-height', height);
}
```

---

Or, for a more general approach, since you want to do it with 3 as well, here's a plugin form:

```
$.fn.setMinHeight = function(setCount) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i+=setCount) {
    var curSet = this.slice(i, i+setCount), 
        height = 0;
    curSet.each(function() { height = Math.max(height, $(this).height()); })
          .css('min-height', height);
  }
  return this;
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$("div.large").setMinHeight(2); //or 3, etc
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvess/Djywr/166/).

Comment: Don't know why you haven't been notified as having the correct answer. This solution was just what I was looking for. Thanks!