# Use Jquery to grab pairs Even/ODD, Even/ODD, Even/ODD

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab **Even,Odd** pairs of several `<p>` tags based on the class name of the `<p>` tags. An example of the code I am trying to get working:

**CSS**

```
body p{
 display: none;
}
```

**HTML**: (my solution **cannot** have id attributes, and they all have to be the same class name)

```
<p class="storyline">Random sentence one</p>
<p class="storyline">Random sentence two</p>
<p class="storyline">Random sentence three</p>
<p class="storyline">Random sentence four</p>
<p class="storyline">Random sentence five</p>
<p class="storyline">Random sentence six</p>
<p class="storyline">Random sentence seven</p>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 // getting several <p> tags with the same class name
 $(".storyline").each(function(index) {

   //Need to grab,  even/odd  even/odd  even/odd,  to be faded in until either, none left, or fade in last individual item
   $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000);
});
});
```

Currently I am only able to load each `<p>` tag individually. I am looking to load pairs such as index points, `[0][1]     [2][3]      [4][5]` ... and so on until there is either nothing left or a **stand alone item that needs to load individually**.

If anyone could help with this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice if you could include some HTML on which this code works so that we could have an example of the code not working, and you would have examples of the code working in answers. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a (non-)working example.

Comment: I updated the question to include what the html would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Found something that worked here .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2358665/10896569

Changed the code to meet my needs to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var p; 
  p=true; 
  $('p.storyline:even').each(function(index){
    var t=$(this);
    var paired = t.add( $('p.storyline:eq('+(t.index()+1)+')', t.parent()) );
  //call function
    if (p){p=true;paired.delay(3000*index).fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow').addClass('greenc');}
    else  {p=false; paired.delay(3000*index).fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow').addClass('redc');}
  });
});
```